# StreamWrite postscript file ends with Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter, postscript

Below is the piece of code that I am writing for doing some processing on postscript file.

```
    private static void ProcessPostScriptFile(string inFileName, string outFileName)
    {
        var inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inFileName, Encoding.UTF8);
        var outputFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);

        string line;
        while ((line = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Do some processing, just to demo that the issue is not related to my processing 
            outputFile.WriteLine(line);
        }
        inputFile.Close();
        outputFile.Close();
    }
```

The input ps file contains some characters for copyright symbol as:
[image]

However, the output file is showing same line as:
 Copyright � 1991, 2002 Adobe Systems Incorporated.

Can anyone guide me how can I fix this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
var inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inFileName, Encoding.UTF8);
var outputFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
```

to

```
var inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inFileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)); 
var outputFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outFileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the streamreader constructor whit the parameter detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and then use the parameter CurrentEncoding to create the streamwriter